# OSX localhost directory icons appearing as text [access_compat] [AH01797]

Tags: macos, apache, permissions

This issue seems to of come about after i've updated to Sierra. While inspecting the images it shows as `localhost/icons/text.gif`, I created a folder and assigned it `777` and still face the same issue.

The apache error log is getting spammed with the following every time a page is viewed that should be showing the icons. `/usr/share/httpd/icons/` is owned by root with `drwxr-xr-x` permissions.

```
[access_compat:error] [pid 1763] [client ::1:49623] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /usr/share/httpd/icons/unknown.gif, referer: http://localhost/testing/
[access_compat:error] [pid 1763] [client ::1:49623] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /usr/share/httpd/icons/text.gif, referer: http://localhost/testing/
[access_compat:error] [pid 1763] [client ::1:49623] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /usr/share/httpd/icons/folder.gif, referer: http://localhost/testing/
[access_compat:error] [pid 1763] [client ::1:49623] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /usr/share/httpd/icons/compressed.gif, referer: http://localhost/testing/
```

[image: Local folder icons]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open the Apache configuration file using:

```
sudo nano /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

Then enter the following code (you can put it beside the other directory code):

```
<Directory /usr/share/httpd/icons>
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Save the file out with `ctrl-O`, then close the file with `ctrl-X` and restart apache using:

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

that should allow the icons to load.